# How do I unload a module from Bing Maps?

Tags: bing-maps, bing, bing-api

Assume I have loaded a module like auto-suggest like,

`Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest', callback);`

Is there any way available to unload this module? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but there is no need to. Loading it simply downloads the script needed for that part of the API. It's like loading any other JavaScript file into your application, once downloaded, there is no undownloading it.

Comment: In the project I am working on there is a case where I want AutoSuggest module to stop suggesting. So is there any way to suspend or stop it and resume module whenever needed?

Comment: In that case you don't need to unload the module. Simple disconnect the autosuggest manager from the input box using the `detachAutosuggest()` function. Alternatively, simply dispose the autosuggest manager and recreate it when needed.